# Custom Woocommerce checkout field doesn't display any value in admin area

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

In the code below, I show a custom field in checkout order page.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_placeholder');
function custom_checkout_placeholder($checkout)
{
    echo '<div id="customise_checkout_field">';
    woocommerce_form_field('customised_field', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'class' => array(
            'my-field-class form-row-wide'
        ) ,
        'label' => __('Rate our support') ,
        'placeholder' => __('') ,
         'options'   => array( __('Bad'),  __('Good'),  __('Very Good')),
    ) , $checkout->get_value('customised_field'));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Now I want to show this field in admin area.

The code below is not working correctly. Show the label 'Rate our support' in admin but not the answer of the user:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'checkout_field_admin_order', 10, 1 );

    function checkout_field_admin_order( $order ){
    $customised_field = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'customised_field', true );
        echo '<p>'.__('Rate our support', 'woocommerce').': ' . $customised_field . '</p>';
}
```

Any ideas why this code in admin area not working?

Comment: Where is the code for where you save the custom value to the order?  You need to save the data on checkout using the hook woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing part is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['customised_field'] ) ) return;
    if ( empty( $_POST['customised_field'] ) ) return;

    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customised_field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customised_field'] ) );
}
```

And in your las t function you will have:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'checkout_field_admin_order', 10, 1 );

function checkout_field_admin_order( $order ){
$customised_field = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_customised_field', true );
    echo '<p>'.__('Rate our support', 'woocommerce').': ' . $customised_field . '</p>';
}
```

**Update:** also change your first function to:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_placeholder');
function custom_checkout_placeholder($checkout)
{
    echo '<div id="customise_checkout_field">';
    woocommerce_form_field('customised_field', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'class' => array(
            'my-field-class form-row-wide'
        ) ,
        'label' => __('Rate our support') ,
        'placeholder' => __('') ,
        'options'   => array( 
             __('Bad')       => __('Bad'), 
             __('Good')      => __('Good'), 
             __('Very Good') => __('Very Good')
         ),
    ) , $checkout->get_value('customised_field'));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but returns int position of array, not the string option choise

Comment: @user2966853 Ok updated my answer (at the end for your first function)… it should work now.